# How to check if a given marker is inside a area

Tags: javascript, math, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hello everybody o/
I know that this is more a math question than gmap, but I suppose that someone already pass through this =)

In my map, I have circle (actually I have several of them, but this not change the question), like this: http://code.google.com/intl/pt-BR/apis/maps/articles/mvcfun/step6.html

How do I know if a marker (with latitude X and longitude Y) is inside this circle?

Sorry for the bad english, I'm brazillian =p

Answer (score 8):

In Google Maps JavaScript API v3 you can use geometry library. To enable it you have to slightly change the script URL:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=geometry"></script>
```

The library contains utility functions for the computation of geometric data on sphere. You can utilize it to compute the distance of two points given by their latLngs this way:

```
var distanceInMetres = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(latLngCircleCenter, latLngPoint);
```

Now you can easily check if the point is inside the circle (suppose R is in metres):

```
if(distanceInMetres < R)
   alert("in the circle");
```

Answer (score 2):

If (lat1, lon1) and (lat2, lon2) are your two points and R is the radius of the circle around your first point, then the distance between the points is given by the [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) (or the [Great-circle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance)). But I believe that for your problem, the angles are small enough to use this approximation:

[image: Approximate Haversine formula]

and then check whether d^2 is less than the radius R^2.

But if your latitude and longitude differences are larger than a few degrees, you'll want to use the full haversine formula.

Comment: I tried
`if ((Math.pow((x - xc), 2) + Math.pow((y - yc), 2)) < Math.pow(R, 2)){
 alert("Marker inside circle!");
}`
But aways "Marker inside circle!"

Comment: Yeah definitely don't use that, it's not for lat-lon. In fact, I will remove it from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I Recommend you read http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html.  It provides a number of algorithms for computations of this kind.  It includes JavaScript code for the computations.

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you have the coords of circle center (cX,cY) and radius R, and some marker at X,Y you can do the following calculations:

```
var distanceQuad = (X-cX)*(X-cX)+(Y-cY)*(Y-cY)
if (distanceQuad<=(R*R))
{
 alert("Marker inside circle!");
}
```

This is from trigonometry. You calculate distance as sqrt(sqr(deltaX)+sqr(deltaY)) and compare it with circle Radius. Given code is a bit optimized to get rid of calculating square root.

Comment: I tried
`var cX = 37.79457586821203, cY = -122.37932682031499, R = 50, X = 37.791591528681565, Y = -121.81147098535405;
var distanceQuad = (X-cX)*(X-cX)+(Y-cY)*(Y-cY)
if (distanceQuad<=(R*R))
{
 alert("Marker inside circle!");`

But aways "Marker inside circle"

Comment: This will work if you're concerned about linear distances.  The case the OP is concerned about deals with great circle arc lengths which require haversine formulations.

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier than you'd expect. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8531127/376483) including a working jsFiddle example.